# urlopen trouble while trying to download a gzip file

Tags: python, gzip, urllib, urlopen

I am going to use the wiktionary dump for the purpose of POS tagging. Somehow it gets stuck when downloading. Here is my code:

```
import nltk
from urllib import urlopen
from collections import Counter
import gzip

url = 'http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiktionary/latest/enwiktionary-latest-all-titles-in-ns0.gz'
fStream = gzip.open(urlopen(url).read(), 'rb')
dictFile = fStream.read()
fStream.close()

text = nltk.Text(word.lower() for word in dictFile())
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "~/dir1/dir1/wikt.py", line 15, in <module>
fStream = gzip.open(urlopen(url).read(), 'rb')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 34, in open
return GzipFile(filename, mode, compresslevel)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 89, in __init__
fileobj = self.myfileobj = __builtin__.open(filename, mode or 'rb')
TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 6):

You are passing the *downloaded data* to `gzip.open()`, which expects to be passed a filename instead.

The code then tries to open a filename named by the gzipped data, and fails.

Either save the URL data to a file, then use `gzip.open()` on *that*, or decompress the gzipped data using the `zlib` module instead. 'Saving' the data can be as easy as using a `StringIO.StringIO()` in-memory file object:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from urllib import urlopen
import gzip


url = 'http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiktionary/latest/enwiktionary-latest-all-titles-in-ns0.gz'
inmemory = StringIO(urlopen(url).read())
fStream = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=inmemory, mode='rb')
```

Comment: Ah, StringIO, how I love you.

Comment: you could [pass `urlopen()` object as `fileobj`  directly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26435241/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: `GzipFile` expects to be able to seek in the file, the `urlopen()` file object doesn't support seeking.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It was a bug that it is fixed in Python 3.2 and backported to Python 2

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: you mean [this issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue1675951)? I don't see that backported, but I may be missing something.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: that change was never backported as far as I can make out. There are still plenty of seek calls in Python 2.7 `gzip.GZipFile` when reading, and without a `StringIO` wrapper you cannot decompress data loaded from a URL with `urlopen`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yes. It fails on Python 2. I've only run it on Python 3. It means http://bugs.python.org/issue914340 was closed by mistake.

Comment: It demonstrates yet again that you can't believe anyone until you've tried the code yourself.